# Optimise DISTINCT . in mysql from a large Mysql table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a problem with a query, It make more than 1 minutes and I think the problem come from my distinct

My index:
table1  (project_name)
table2 (importer_id,sipplier_id)
table3 (name)

My table 2 have more than 2 millions rows

Here my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.id         AS project_id,
                table1.name       AS project_name,
                table3.id         AS supplier_id,
                table4.report_id as report_id,
                table3.name       AS supplier_name
FROM  table1
         LEFT JOIN  table2 ON table2.project_id = table1.id
         LEFT JOIN  table3 ON table3.id = table2.supplier_id
         LEFT JOIN  table4 ON table4.project_id = table1.id
WHERE table1.id IN
      ('2067', '2068', '2069', '2070', '2072', '2073', '2074', '2083', '2084', '2085', '2086', '2087', '2088', '2089',
       '2090', '2091', '2092', '2093', '2094', '2095', '2096', '2097', '2098', '2100', '2101', '2102', '2103', '2104',
       '2105', '2106', '2107', '2108', '2109', '2110', '2111', '2112', '2113', '2114', '2115', '2116', '2117', '2118',
       '2119', '2120', '2121', '2122', '2123', '2124', '2125', '2126', '2127')
  AND (table2.importer_id IN ('215') OR table2.supplier_id IN ('215'))
```

[image: Explain]

Create table statement for all tables (table 1 table 2 table 3 table 4)

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
                                  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                                  `client_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,

                                  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                                  KEY `FK_wsxix_projects` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2085 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;



CREATE TABLE `table2` (
                          `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

                          `buyer_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `client_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `merchandiser_user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `factory_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `dc_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `supplier_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
                          `importer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
                          `project_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
                          `tier_two_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `store_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                          KEY `buyer_id` (`buyer_id`),
                          KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
                          KEY `merchandiser_user_id` (`merchandiser_user_id`),
                          KEY `FK_po_factory_companies_id` (`factory_id`),
                          KEY `FK_po_dc_companies_id` (`dc_id`),
                          KEY `index_po_parentid` (`parent_id`),
                          KEY `index_purchaseorders_cie` (`supplier_id`),
                          KEY `index_poimporter_cie` (`importer_id`),
                          KEY `index_purchaseorders_project` (`project_id`),
                          KEY `facory_importer_id` (`factory_id`,`importer_id`),
                          KEY `posu` (`project_id`,`supplier_id`),
                          KEY `store_id` (`store_id`),
                          KEY `tier_two_id` (`tier_two_id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34959 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;






CREATE TABLE `table3` (
                                   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                   `parent_company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                                   `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
                                   `type_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                                   `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

                                   `use_majora_majorb` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                                   `aql_presets_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                                   `fabx_presets_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                                   `group_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                                   `contact_number` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
                                   `unit_number` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
                                   `use_factory_location` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                                   `restrict_users_access_to_sub_companies` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Using for share function so far',
                                   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                                   KEY `index_wsxix_companies_aql_presets_id` (`aql_presets_id`),
                                   KEY `index_company_type` (`type_id`),
                                   KEY `index_companies_group_id` (`group_id`),
                                   KEY `fk_wsxix_companies_fabx_presets_idx` (`fabx_presets_id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=992 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;



CREATE TABLE `table4` (
                                         `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                         `report_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                                         `project_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
                                         PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                                         KEY `index_project_reports_projects` (`project_id`),
                                         KEY `index_project_reports_reports` (`report_id`),
                                         CONSTRAINT `fk_project_reports_projects` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `wsxix_projects` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                                         CONSTRAINT `fk_project_reports_reports` FOREIGN KEY (`report_id`) REFERENCES `wsxix_report_types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=138 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Show DDL of all tables.

Comment: Do you really need "distinct"? It appears the query optimizer thinks checking uniqueness of names is cheaper than finding all the IDs in your "in" clause.

Comment: Yes, I really need "Distinct" , without distinct I have 12 766 066 (query take 8 ms to execute) . rows and with the distinct I have 11 081 rows (53,4 seconds to execute)

Comment: @Kouja Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` statements for all of your tables. Akina already asked you for this, and you didn't acknowledge his request. Many people, including myself, will refuse to spend time answering a query-optimization question where not only is that information not provided, but where the asker ignores requests for that information. I see possible things to try, but the risk of you just not responding to the contents of my answer means I am unwilling to invest the time in creating such an answer.

Comment: @WillemRenzema updated

Comment: @Kouja Thank you. Can there ever be more than a single value for `importer_id` or `supplier_id`? I notice you are using `IN` there, but only one value is present, so can't tell if sometimes the query will have more than one value passed to it for either of those columns in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @WillemRenzema can have more than one value, but most of the time is only one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here is my first attempt. Keep in mind that this is a rather difficult query to optimize, given all the `OR` and `IN` statements.

Try the following rewritten query. It uses a semi-join to avoid the need for `DISTINCT`, which may result in a decent performance improvement.

```
SELECT
table1.id         AS project_id,
table1.name       AS project_name,
table3.id         AS supplier_id,
table4.report_id  AS report_id,
table3.name       AS supplier_name
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
ON EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table2
  WHERE table2.project_id = table1.id
  AND table2.supplier_id = table3.id
  AND (table2.importer_id IN ('215') OR table2.supplier_id IN ('215'))
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4
ON table4.project_id = table1.id
WHERE table1.id IN
  ('2067', '2068', '2069', '2070', '2072', '2073', '2074', '2083', '2084', '2085', '2086', '2087', '2088', '2089',
   '2090', '2091', '2092', '2093', '2094', '2095', '2096', '2097', '2098', '2100', '2101', '2102', '2103', '2104',
   '2105', '2106', '2107', '2108', '2109', '2110', '2111', '2112', '2113', '2114', '2115', '2116', '2117', '2118',
   '2119', '2120', '2121', '2122', '2123', '2124', '2125', '2126', '2127')
```

Then, add the following indexes, which should help performance as well:

```
ALTER TABLE table4
ADD INDEX sowr1 (project_id,report_id)

ALTER TABLE table2
ADD INDEX sowr2 (project_id,supplier_id,importer_id)
```

Run the query at least twice, and ignore the timing on the first run, so you can avoid the InnoDB buffer cache from giving inaccurate speed results.

Let me know how fast it runs. Then, if it still needs more improvement, provide the EXPLAIN plan for this query, as without your data at hand it is difficult to see exactly how well these changes will work.